# Rewrite "IN" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

Recently I've been working on some software which has a system in place that allows you to list specific data from an MSSQL table and display it in a web-based GUI. It has a few constrictions, though.

When comparing text, the only operators allowed are *NOT NULL* and *LIKE*.

Furthermore, every statement starts with *SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE*.

The reason for that is the way the software we're using is programmed. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to change it and the developers don't seem to be planning on addressing the issue either.

This has been causing quite some trouble, but so far, there have always been ways to rewrite the statements.

Now, I've reached a point where I'm stuck. I've created a view that selects a specific subset of MyTable's rows. Now I want to display these

**Tl;dr:**

If I have this piece of code which I cannot modify, only append to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
```

how do I perform an inner join with a different table from there, without using *IN*?

-

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why both MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry, must have been a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the laugh of it, I'd do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 0 = 1 UNION SELECT whatIWant FROM whereIWant
```

The 0 = 1 criteria discards all results from MyTable, only the right part of the union will return results. A problem is that you will still have to handle the columns from MyTable.

Comment: Interesting. If you go that far, then why not simply `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 0 = 1; SELECT whatIWant FROM whereIWant` and you don't need to worry about `MyTable` anymore? :-)

Comment: @RacilHilan I don't know its interface but it's plausible that it would only accept a single SQL statement

Comment: It's not the interface, but the db engine. Assuming that the interface sends the query as a string, it does not know what it means so it does not care. As for the db engine, most engines will execute both queries and return the result of the last one.

Comment: Well we don't know, I doubt it's the RDBMS that forces him to work with the `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE` fragment. I guessed he had an application sending queries, and maybe it sends them as text - then you're right - or maybe it does some additional verification. I think PDO or a jdbc driver - just to cite two - would refuse to send two queries when they expect to send one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestion has lead me to my final query, which is a lot less messy than I expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE 
exists (SELECT * from othertable as t2 where t2.col=MyTable.col)
```